# Will this DeWalt #8 screw countersink bit be good for 1/16" aluminum?

Tags: screws

I want to screw aluminum to wood. If it was wood to wood, this bit:

[image: https://d2pbmlo3fglvvr.cloudfront.net/product/full/Z1K9wvfo5oy.JPG]
<sup>Image from [zoro.com](https://www.zoro.com/dewalt-countersink-8-with-1164-in-bit-dw2568/i/G7635205/)</sup>

makes perfect sense for the pilot and counter sink. However, it makes no mention of if the counter sink part would handle aluminum.

Alternatively, should I use this 1/2" Ryobi countersink:

[image: http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/20/20258340-a7f8-4078-9071-5d3534cd125f_400.jpg]
<sup>Image from [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ryobi-1-2-in-High-Speed-Steel-Countersink-A10CS72/205472330?keyword=ryobi+a10cs72)</sup>

and a separate drill bit for the pilot hole?

Comment: By "screw aluminum into wood" you mean "put a screw through a hole in aluminum to fasten it to wood", right?

Comment: Yes. The screw is a normal zinc screw.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you can use the same tools you'd use for wood to work with aluminum. I've done a number of projects using aluminum bar and angle stock with my woodworking tools, including a miter saw.

However, since the metal is much harder, you'd probably have an easier time doing the drilling and countersinking separately. I'd drill with a standard high-speed bit, and use a countersink like the Ryobi you linked to finish.

On a related note, you'll not have much room for error when countersinking 1/16" stock. You might be better off with pan-head screws.

Comment: My main issue, which the guy at the hardware store warned me about, is I drilled too fast and aluminum shavings stuck to the bit like melted wax. My second issue was it took to long at the slower speed on my drill.

Comment: @JustinDearing - Too fast shouldn't have been an issue, drilling for *too long* is though (a kind of work-hardening). You weren't pushing hard enough to make chips; you were galling it. But as mentioned don't push too hard ;) *over*-countersinking aluminum is my usual problem.

Comment: The tapered style drill bits need to be  handled very carefully when drilling through aluminum. They have a tenancy to want to pull themselves down into the drill hole with a surprisingly aggressive force. So use care to clamp down the work piece and get both hands securely on your drill before starting the hole.

Comment: True. Same with DeWalt's pilot-point bits. the primary cutting edge grabs hard with its square edge profile.